# I need to take out duplicates from date column in cross tab in crystal report 8.0

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

​In cross Tab:
One column is date. I need to show only month in following order fiscal year order:
April
May 
june 
July 
August 
September 
october 
november 
december 
january 
febuary
march.

It should not be more than one time. While I am trying I am getting duplicates months in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may happen because of many causes. My opinion is, you should put some screen shot or your codes here, so it easier for experts to understand you problem.

this is what i can suggest to you

- if you have many tables linked together, please double check if the link is correct or not

OR

- you can select Database-->Select Distinct Record at the menu

Comment: Now I am getting this one using cross tab:

                2006 2007 20008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 

September

october

november

december

january

febuary

march

september

january

november

,,

etc

But I need this one: Our Fiscal Year starts from April to March. Based on our fiscal year it should give the result :

               FY 2006 FY2007 FY 2008 FY2009 FY2010 FY2011 FY2012

April

May

June

July

August

September

October

November

December

January

Febuary

March